# ColorSetting is in onsync but getting "it looks like that device hasn't been set up yet" when issuing voice command

Tags: actions-on-google

I am attempting to use the "ColorSetting" device trait on a device type that does not have ColorSetting trait by default.  I have added it to my onsync handler following the examples [here](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/colorsetting#request)

However when I issue a voice command such as "make [the device] blue" I get the "It looks like that device hasn't been set up yet" error.  I have added other traits such as "Brightness" to this same device and that works fine.  However trying to change the color via the ColorSetting trait causes that error before it even gets to the "onExecute" handler.  Any thoughts?

Edit: sync request for relevant portion:

```
    "id": "463569999",
    "type": "action.devices.types.AIRFRESHENER",
    "traits": [
        "action.devices.traits.OnOff",
        "action.devices.traits.Modes",
        "action.devices.traits.Toggles",
        "action.devices.traits.ColorSetting",
        "action.devices.traits.Brightness"
    ],
    "name": {
        "defaultNames": [
            "463569999"
        ],
        "name": "463569999",
        "nicknames": [
            "Den"
        ]
    },
    "attributes": {
        "pausable": true,
        "colorModel": "rgb",
        "colorTemperatureRange": {
            "temperatureMinK": 2000,
            "temperatureMaxK": 9000
        },
        "commandOnlyColorSetting": false,
...
```

Comment: Can you provide more details on your sync response?

Comment: { id: '463569999',
type: 'action.devices.types.AIRFRESHENER',
traits: 
[ 'action.devices.traits.OnOff',
'action.devices.traits.Modes',
'action.devices.traits.Toggles',
'action.devices.traits.ColorSetting',
'action.devices.traits.Brightness' ],
name: { defaultNames: ['463569999'], name: '463569999', nicknames: ['Den'] },
attributes: 
{ pausable: true,
colorModel: 'rgb',
colorTemperatureRange: [Object],
commandOnlyColorSetting: false,
availableModes: [Array],
availableToggles: [Array] } } ]

Comment: Can you provide the full string? Having `colorTemperatureRange` being defined as `[Object]` makes it unclear what those values are, if they have an effect. Running `JSON.stringify(device)` will print out a serialized string.

Comment: Ok, I updated the original post with the sync response.  The sync response for the colorsetting portion is the same as what is on the google actions page:  https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/traits/colorsetting

Comment: Is the name too vague? If you try to make it more specific, like "reading lamp", it may be able to be found.

Comment: The device name works fine for the other commands that are in the sync response, like on/off, and the other modes and toggles.  It only returns that error when attempting to use the colorsetting trait.

Comment: I tried renaming to "reading lamp" as well just to test but receive the same error

Comment: I've created a bug report.

Comment: Thanks Nick.  Is it possible to link me to the bug report for status updates on it?  In the meantime, is it an option for me to request a new mode on the google smarthome github with a list of colors?

Comment: It's not a public bug. A new mode with colors could create grammar conflicts, and would not be added.